# How to refer the LESS file in asp.net webforms?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, less

I am working on an asp.net webforms C# project. I have created a LESS file and compiled. When I used it in my aspx file head section as part of a CSS, the class in the LESS file is not recognized. I see "Missing property name before the colon (:) in the "(Property) : (Value)" declaration" message.

My LESS file, TreeviewStyle.less:

```
split-into-two{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    -moz-column-gap: 50px;
}

body {
}
```

My aspx file

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link href="TreeviewStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">

     div > ul {
         .split-into-two;
     }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Isn't it that LESS file is compiled to a .css file and then you reference it? EDIT: I was not wrong, the official [site](http://lesscss.org/) states that it is indeed compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: After OP's comment, here is my answer:

```
div > ul {
    .split-into-two;
}
```

This syntax is invalid. I think you tried to set the `.split-into-two` class to every `ul` element nested in `div`, but you can't do that via css. You either have to apply the class manually to every `ul` in your template, use jQuery (or something) similiar to do that from JavaScript code, or modify your less file to get this result:

```
div > ul, .split-into-two{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    -moz-column-gap: 50px;
}
```

*Keeping the old part for the sake of consistency:*

You can't refer to the .less file **directly**.

First, you have to compile it using the `lessc` command line tool:

```
$ lessc TreeviewStyle.less TreeviewStyle.css
```

Then, you change your .apsx file to include the compiled css file:

```
<link href="TreeviewStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

[Here](http://lesscss.org/) is the source.
Please, do a more thorough research next time.

Comment: Actually I have already compiled into TreeviewStyle.css and referred it as you have explained. I have posted the wrong code by mistake. Still I was getting the same error

Comment: Okay, I've modified my answer, take a look now.

Comment: Hi Jakub, I have added jQuery code to add the class to UL elements. Still doesn't work with TreeviewStyle.css. However it works when I add .split-into-two with all the CSS values within the aspx page. Thanks

Comment: I found the issue. In the LESS fie I didn't have a "." in front of the class name. Once I put it it worked fine.

Comment: As you have posted this, I've looked at your question and now it seems obvious... Anyways, good that you managed to fix the problem.